# implement joins with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to implement  following join query

```
SELECT * from users as u

LEFT JOIN `table1` as ou

ON ou.user_id = u.id

LEFT JOIN table2 as o

ON o.id = ou.orid

LEFT JOIN table3 as p

ON o.pra_id = p.id;
```

with my laravel model so i create a function named alldata() in my user model with following code

```
public function alldata()

{

    return $this

        ->leftjoin('table1','users.id','=','table1.user_id')

        ->leftjoin('table2','table1.orid','=','table2.id')

        ->leftjoin('table3','table2.pra_id','=','table3.id');

}
```

> now when i try to access the data by $gd = User::find(1)->getall() it returns results with all the table 
>   but when i try to acces $gd = User::all()->alldata() it gaves error mathod not found 
>   how can i resolve this
>   thanks

Comment: Should your `alldata` function be `getall` in the example your giving? 

I think it should be but any way give https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships a look your better establishing the relationships on the model rather than doing a load of messy joins manually.

Answer (score 1):

The User::find(1) function returns an single instance of the object (or NULL if not found).

The User::all() function returns a Collection of all User objects.

You need to create a query then get() the results as follows...

```
public static function alldata()
    {

    return self::query()
        ->leftjoin('table1','users.id','=','table1.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('table2','table1.orid','=','table2.id')
        ->leftjoin('table3','table2.pra_id','=','table3.id')
        ->get();
}
```

Assuming your your alldata() method is in the User class you can call the function with the following code:

```
User::alldata();
```

Laravel has a excellent database relationship system which is most defiantly worth looking at. It would make queries like the one above much simpler...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I assume the alldata() method is on your User model?

I have updated my answer.

Comment: no sir its again Using $this when not in object context